# stm32cubeIDE and using git

Tags: git, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to create process for development with CubeMX/CubeIDE projects.
I'm seeing pathing issues that show up when my project is moved. Which also means when it's cloned to another computer.

Simple steps I've done to reproduce this:
Created a new project with CubeMX. It generated the code and then imported to CubeIDE.

Project works and builds.

Now, I move the project to a different directory. (Which also happens when I clone it)

The project can no longer find files in the "Drivers" subfolder.

If I look at one of the files on the original (working) project I can see how it resolves:
[image]
Once I've moved the folder it resolves different and completely changes the pathing:
[image]

In practice I will want to push and then clone these projects. However, each attempt ends the same way. The pathing resolves differently then where it was generated leaving the project unbuildable.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question lies behind STM32CubeMX.
In CubeMX, if not specifically told to do so the application will generate Linked directories for eclipse. These do not relocate well.

In order to work around this, in CubeMX, in the “Project Manager” tab, under the “Code Generation” (on the left) make sure that  “Copy only the necessary library files” is selected.

This will  create a completely independent source code tree that can be moved, and used in source code control without issues.